# User Defined Variable in MySQL Insert Query

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, insert

I just wondering is it possible to use my variable for insert query?
I'm going to insert a new record to my table. The primary key on my table is numeric value (`int`). To give a unique value I need to get the latest key (`MAX (menuId)`) from my table and then increment that value by 1.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT @newId := COALESCE( MAX( menuId ) , 0 ) +1
FROM msMenu;

INSERT INTO msMenu( @newId,  'My Menu', 1) ;
```

Does MySQL variable only allowed in stored procedure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you make your primary key `auto-increment`? you don't even have to insert the id.

Comment: nice idea :) but i the auto-increment key doesn't allow me to insert previous deleted number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    INSERT INTO msMenu (column1, column2 , column3)
    SELECT  COALESCE( MAX( menuId ) , 0 ) +1 ,'My Menu', '1'  
    FROM msMenu;
```

EDIT2:

```
 SET @newId = (select COALESCE( MAX( menuId ) , 0 ) +1 from msMenu)
 INSERT INTO msMenu (column1, column2 , column3)
 SELECT  @newId ,'My Menu', '1'  
 FROM msMenu;
```

Comment: I've try that code :) and it's work. But is it possible to declare a variable in a normal query (not in stored procedure)?

Comment: @WillyLazuardi try this edit2 but im not sure , so if its not working tell me to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sql;

```
SELECT @newId := COALESCE( MAX( menuId ) , 0 ) +1 FROM msMenu;
INSERT INTO msMenu values ( (select @newId), 'My Menu', 1) ;
```